# Laravel belongsToMany Get Middle Table Value

Tags: laravel

```
PO:
po_uuid
name

GT:
gt_uuid
name
units

POGT:
po_uuid
gt_uuid
units
```

That is my laravel code:

`$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\GroupTask', 'purchase_order_group_tasks', 'purchase_order_uuid', 'group_tasks_uuid');`

Is it possible to get POGT.units as the value? In my case, it shows GT.units as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to add the pivot value to your relationship.

```
$this
    ->belongsToMany('App\Models\GroupTask', 'purchase_order_group_tasks', 'purchase_order_uuid', 'group_tasks_uuid')
    ->withPivot('units');
```

Now on your relation you can say `$purchaseOrder->groupTasks->first()->pivot->units` to get the pivot table value.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are wanting to use is the `hasManyThrough` relationship:

Modify to the following:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Post',
        'App\User',
        'country_id', // Foreign key on users table...
        'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
        'id', // Local key on countries table...
        'id' // Local key on users table...
    );
}
```

I think this would go in `POGT` model

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\PO',
        'App\GT',
        'gt_uuid', // Foreign key on PO table...
        'po_uuid', // Foreign key on GT table...
        'id', // Local key on POGT table...
        'id' // Local key on GT table...
    );
}
```

Using this method will return only the middle table data.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote proper [ManyToMany relations](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) all you need:

```
$GT->pivot->units;
//or
$PO->pivot->units;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\GroupTask', 'purchase_order_group_tasks', 'purchase_order_uuid', 'group_tasks_uuid')->withPivot('colume_name');

return $relationName->pivot->colume_name
```